# Creating a Timer in C

Tags: c, timer

How do I create a timer? A timer like the one in Visual Basic; you set an interval, if the timer is enabled it waits until the time is up.

I don't want to use an existing library because I want to know how it works.

So.. I just hope someone could explain me how timers work and maybe give me an example of code to create my own - if it's not too advanced.

Edit:
I wanna create one for a linux system.

Comment: Which OS are you targeting ?

Comment: Are you familiar with threads and/or processes?  If not this would be difficult to explain until you do.

Comment: I don't know how Visual Basic makes this appear, but suspending and waking up are operations implemented in the operating system.  If you don't want to use an existing library, you'll just be making 'bare' operating system calls - not too much point really.

Comment: My target -> mainly linux but I'd like to create one for windows and linux.

Comment: Looks like someone needs to learn about event-driven programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    printf("wait\n");
    sleep(3);
    printf("time elapsed\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This seems to deserve a downvote. The OP specifically asked not to use libraries...

Comment: Well he accepted the answer, maybe he wasn't too sure of what he was asking.

Answer (score 5):

The following is a very basic example which will run under Linux. If you look at the manual page of `signal` you will see it is deprecated in favor of `sigaction`. Important is not to forget the `volatile`, otherwise the `while` loop may not terminate depending on optimizations. Note also how `SIGALRM` is a highly shared resource which may be used by other timer facilities and there is only one.

The program will print `Waiting` for three seconds and than quit after printing `Finally ...` once.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

volatile int mark = 0;

void trigger(int sig)
{
        mark = 1;
}

int main(void)
{
        signal(SIGALRM, trigger);
        alarm(3);

        while (!mark)
        {
                printf("Waiting\n");
        }
        printf("Finally ...\n");

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: And use 100% CPU for the task.